# How to read a 16-bit number from a file in C#?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I have a requirement which involves some level of bit operations. I have no experience of bit operations.

From the file byte I have to pick the fifth and sixth byte.

[image]

and have to calculate the value from this formula, which is explained like this for the given example

> byte 5 - LSB, byte 6 MSB. In example offset will be 598 (LSB * (MSB <<
>   8))

How did they get 598 for the given example?

I know LSB means least significant bit and MSB is most significant bit.

So is 8 the LSB of 5th byte and 0 the MSB of sixth byte?

Or do I have to convert 98 and 05 to bits and then have to find out these two values?

I want to code this formula in C#.

Comment: Those are Hexadecimal.  So bitshifting by any multiple of 4 bits will preserve the digits.  Just like multiplying by 10 in decimal keeps the same digits but just shifts the decimal point or adds zeros.  0x05 << 8 = 0x0500.  0x0500 | 0x98 = 0x0598.

Comment: and you likely meant  `|` not `*` when you wrote `(LSB * (MSB << 8))`

Comment: @Wyck - Thank you very much for the explanation! 
But when we say this `0x05 << 8 = 0x0500. 0x0500 | 0x98 = 0x0598` we are considering the whole data I mean `05` and `98` then what is LSB and MSB here?

Comment: 0x98 is defined as LSB , 0x05 is MSB. Most significant _byte_. A change of "1" in this byte has greater effect on the number as a change of "1" in the other (that's how I used to remeber it).

Comment: @Fildor - Ah ok! Got it! Just one last question, in my requirement it is written that `598` means the value that has come out as a result is the offset from where the actual data starts and from where my program should start reading data. So should I search for `598` value in the file to know the start of the data or 598 is the ordinal position count of byte from where I should start reading, meaning from 598th byte

Comment: In short: It's the byte count.

Comment: If that's an offset stored in the file then it's probably referring to the `0x598`th byte.  Which is an offset of 1432 bytes (decimal).  You'll have to consult the text of your specification/documentation to be sure.  (in other words, no, don't go looking for the value 0x0598 in the file)

Comment: Thank you very much Fildor and Wyck!! You guys helped me a lot!

Comment: I don't know if the question is off-topic, but please do not add "I know this is off-topic" waffle. You are an experienced user, and will know that this is a mess that someone needs to clean up. Basically, if it is not a good question that would help future readers, don't post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MSB` also stands for `Most significant byte`.

```
    var data = new byte[] { 0xA9, 0x43, 0x50, 0x49, 0x00, 0x98, 0x05, 0x28 };

    ushort value = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, 5);

    Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("X4"));
```

`BitConverter.ToUInt16` will read two bytes from `data` array starting at index `5`, i.e. `0x98` and `0x05`. Then it will apply formula to calculate the result which is `0x0598`.

The formula depends on CPU architecture [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

[BitConverter.ToUInt16](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.touint16?view=netcore-3.1#System_BitConverter_ToUInt16_System_Byte___System_Int32_)

Comment: Thanks! It worked! But how come `BitConverter.ToUInt16` is returning the result I expect? I mean is this function returns the result based on same formula?

Comment: @PawanNogariya: yes. This is not unique problem. Thousands of Pawans in the world faced the same issue, so they made special method for them to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't know if that was a sarcastic reply but I actually asked the question because I didn't know that the formula that is given to me in the requirement is actually a generic formula and not specific to my project's business.

Comment: @PawanNogariya: it is generic formula.

Comment: Could you help me with one more thing? The requirement says that the result which is `0x598` is the offset from where I have to start reading data. Do you know how to do this in C#? I mean I can read it if it is decimal but reading from `0x598`th byte I don't know

Answer (score 1):

You aren't going to need to deal with individual bits. These are hexadecimal values, so 98 is a single byte and 05 is a single byte.

It also looks like there is an error in the conversion. You need to add the LSB to the shifted MSB, not multiply. 598 = 0x98 + (0x05 << 8). The <<8 operator is shifting your MSB over by one byte (same as multiplying it by 256).

The byte at index position 5 is: 98 (hex)
The byte at index position 6 is: 05 (hex)

In which case the result is 0598 or 589 (hex)

If you do the math in C# you'll likely be seeing the result as an integer, which is 1432.